# JPA: Automatically delete data after timeinterval

Tags: jpa, triggers, cron, h2, resteasy

I've the following scenario:

Data will be created by the sender on the server.
If the receiver won't request the data within (for example) three days, the data should be deleted otherwise the receiver gets the data and after getting the data, the data will be deleted.

In other words:

The data should only exist for a limited time.

I could create a little jar-file which will delete the data manually, probably started as a cron-job. But i think, that that is a very bad solution.

Is it possible to create a trigger with JPA/Java EE that will be called after a specific time period? As far as i know trigger can only be called after/before insert, update, delete events. So that won't be a solution.

Note: I'm currently using H2-Database and Wildfly for my RESTeasy application. But i might change that in future, so the solution should be adaptive.

Best regards,

Maik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE brings everything you need. You can [@Schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) a periodically executed cleanup job:

```
@Singleton
public class Cleanup {

    @Schedule(minute = "*/5")
    public void clean() {
        // will be called every 5 minutes
    }

}
```

Or you programmatically create a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Timer.html) which will be executed after a certain amount of time:

```
@Singleton
public class Cleanup {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    public void deleteLater(long id) {
        String timerInfo = MyEntity.class.getName() + ':' + id;
        long timeout = 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
        timerService.createTimer(timeout, timerInfo);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void handleTimeout(Timer timer) {
        Serializable timerInfo = timer.getInfo(); // the information you passed to the timer
    }

}
```

More information can be found in the [Timer Service Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm#BNBOY).